# How do you COUNT outside of the WHERE statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table - something like:

```
A|B
1|1
1|2
1|3
2|1
2|3
2|4
2|5
3|5
```

My query returns the distinct values in A if they coincide with a value in B of 1 or 2 - so

```
A
1
2
```

I am trying to also return the original count of the 1's and 2's in column A - to get something like

```
A|Count
1|3
2|4
```

Is there a simple way to get this count please?
However, the COUNT (A) returns the number of A's coinciding with the initial WHERE statement:

```
A|Count
1|2
2|1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
SELECT a, (SELECT count(*) FROM t t2 WHERE t2.a = t.a) a_count
FROM t
WHERE b IN (1,2)
GROUP BY a
```

Answer (score 2):

My SQL might be a bit rusty, but I think you can do:

```
SELECT A, count(*) AS Count FROM MyTable WHERE B IN (1, 2) GROUP BY A;
```

Comment: Note that I'm not 100% sure this syntax works in MySQL, but it would work in Oracle, and I think its close to ANSI standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.A, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.B)
FROM MyTable t1 JOIN MyTable t2 ON (t1.A = t2.A)
WHERE t2.A = t2.B
GROUP BY t1.A;
```

Comment: There might be more than one value of t2.A = t2.B.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Bill Karwin's answer:

```
SELECT
  A,
  Counted.CountOfB
FROM
  MyTable
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT A, COUNT(B) AS CountOfB
    FROM   MyTable
    GROUP BY  A
  ) Counted ON Counted.A = MyTable.A
WHERE
  {your filter for MyTable}
```